# How to filter records for fixed, regular blocks of time in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm interested in capturing user behaviour during specific hours of the day, everyday. Suppose I have a dataframe with the columns

```
+-------+-----+----------+
| start | end | activity |
+-------+-----+----------+
```

Both `start` and `end` are in Unix timestamps. Is there any way to filter for a specific interval of time, like 10 a.m. to 11 a.m. every day in PySpark? Note that `start` may start before 10 and `end` may end after 11. I want to find all time periods which overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can get hour from timestamp.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

day_timestamps = 24*60*60
hour_timestamps = 60*60
hour = 10
tmstmp2hour = lambda tm: (tm%day_timestamp)/hour_timestamp 
df.filter( 
   (tmstmp2hour(F.col('start'))<hour) 
    & 
   (tmstmp2hour(F.col('end'))>hour)
)
```

Comment: That doesn't really work. Say if I start my activity at 10.30 a.m. and end at 10.59 a.m., this won't be able to capture the right rows. The inequalities have to be `<=` and `>=`. Even so, if I want to capture behaviour across days, say from 11 p.m. to 1 a.m., I can have something that starts at 2 a.m. and end at 5 a.m. which will be flagged up in this function even though it doesn't fulfill the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works for your problem

Create a DataFrame, assuming you have unix timestamp

```
l1 = [(1541585700,1541585750,'playing'), (1531305900,1541589300, 'fishing'), (1541589400,1541589500,'working'),(1530919800, 1530923400, 'across-night')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l1, ['start','end','activity'])
df.show()
```

Initialize your range in 24 hour format, you can make it as a part of dataframe to speed up

```
capStart = 23 #11 pm, 
capEnd = 1 # 1am

df = df.withColumn('startSec', df.start%(24*60*60))
df = df.withColumn('endSec', df.end%(24*60*60))
df = df.withColumn('match', (df.startSec >= capStart*60*60) & (df.endSec <= capEnd*60*60))
df.show()
+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+-----+
|     start|       end|activity|startSec|endSec|match|
+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+-----+
|1541585700|1541585750| playing|   36900| 36950|false|
|1531305900|1541589300| fishing|   38700| 40500|false|
|1541589400|1541589500| working|   40600| 40700|false|
|1530919800|1530923400|   night|   84600|  1800| true|
+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+-----+
#Filter the result
df = df.filter(df.match == True)
df.show()
+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+-----+
|     start|       end|activity|startSec|endSec|match|
+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+-----+
|1530919800|1530923400|   night|   84600|  1800| true|
+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+-----+
```